# What does Windows Desktop (5) mean in context of .net 5?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

I saw [this link for the Registry class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry?view=windowsdesktop-5.0), which states it's for the Windows Desktop 5 "Version" of .net. I searched for what that means, but unfortunately the noise to signal ratio on such a search is large.

So what does Windows Desktop 5 mean? I know what .net is, .net framework, .net core, .net standard, UWP, the various Xamarin "versions"... But not what Windows Desktop is.

It's even stranger considering that I created a new .net 5 WPF project and typed in `Registry`, clicked CTRL+. and got the option to add `using Microsoft.Win32;` without doing anything else. So it seems to be simply part of .net 5 even though changing the "version" to .net 5 tells me that:

> The requested page is not available for .NET 5.

Comment: Here you go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview  Note: You don't need to specify the ".WindowsDesktop" part for .net 5.0 or later.

Comment: @MatthewWatson OK. In the 2nd link you supplied it says that from .net 5 and on this is not needed. Instead, setting UseWPF to true will do that automatically. Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewWatson Do you want to convert that into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for .Net Project SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview) states:

> The .NET SDK is the base SDK for .NET. The other SDKs reference the
> .NET SDK, and projects that are associated with the other SDKs have
> all the .NET SDK properties available to them. The Web SDK, for
> example, depends on both the .NET SDK and the Razor SDK.

One of the SDKs that it mentions is `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop` which is

> The .NET Desktop SDK, which includes Windows Forms (WinForms) and
> Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF).

Version 5 of this (for *.net 5.0*) is the "Windows Desktop 5" that the documentation for the `Registry` class is talking about.

This is further documented in the [MSBuild reference for .NET Desktop SDK projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props-desktop) which is a

> reference for the MSBuild properties and items that you use to
> configure Windows Forms (WinForms) and Windows Presentation Foundation
> (WPF) projects with the .NET Desktop SDK.